# Excel VBA Userform Initialize Error

Tags: excel, vba

I've had an Excel VBA addin I've developed over many years. Many users have used this addin on Windows on both Excel 2007 and Excel 2010; it has even worked on Macbook. For the first time, a user is getting an error in Windows Excel 2010 when clicking a button I've added to a ribbon to bring up a form.

The error is 'Compile error: Variable not defined'. I am using Option Explicit throughout the code, but there is no variable being defined when the userform initializes. I've compiled from within the VBA editor using Debug...Compile VBAProject and get no errors. I've googled this and read many posts but nowhere has this error been associated with a userform initializing.

I have this code in the click event of a button I've added to a new ribbon:

```
Sub DisplayForm4Calc1(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
On Error Resume Next
    frmAA.Show
End Sub
```

I have this code in frmAA, just initializing some controls:

```
Option Explicit
Public myPrevious As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
On Error Resume Next
    refNumerator.value = ""
    refDenominator.value = ""
    MultiPage.value = 3
End Sub
```

The error is highlighting the line 'Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()'.

Comment: Use `F8` in debugging to step through the code and identify which line actually raises the error. Also, get rid of your `On Error Resume Next` statements.

Comment: Changing or assigning the value to a `MultiPage` control may trigger that control's `_Change` event, too, so the error may be in that function.

Comment: @David—Unfortunately this is on a user's computer in another county, and I can't debug on their machine; the error is not coming up on any machine here. I tried removing the `On Error Resume Next` statements and they're testng it again. And, there is no `_Change` event on the `MultiPage` control.

Comment: Would all the global scope variables be created when the Initialize function is first invoked?  If so, perhaps one of those variables is dependent on an external object that isn't on the user's computer.

Comment: @David—I sent the user a version without the `On Error Resume Next` lines and it worked for them. I will investigate more especially given the advice from @Yow. But it's great that they can use it. Thanks!

Comment: That's absolutely bizarre!! If anything, the `On Error Resume Next` should be hiding/suppressing the error message (unless user has the VBE configured to "break on all errors" -- which is unlikely unless s/he is actively working in VBA), and so removing it **should** raise the error, if there is one...

Comment: @David—I'm going to go through using the whole app over the phone with them, for vacation and timing reasons not til July 26, so I'll see if anything else is raised on their machine. It is baffling. (And sorry I have a reputation of just 8 so I can't vote up your answer.)

Comment: no worries, I haven't actually "answered" anything yet :) you might try to do some sort of web-conference that would allow you to remotely access the user's computer, for purpose of debugging.

Comment: I would look closely at is whether there are any event procedures for the `MultiPage` control (you've mentioned that there is not a `_Change` event, but there might be other event(s) raised when accessing the control's `.Value` property, and the root cause may have been deeper in there somewhere. Also, unhandled errors can cause state loss of the ribbon object, global variables, etc., and that could raise an `Object Required` error but I wouldn't expect "Variable not defined"...